# Select a multi value minimum from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Experimenting with PostgreSQL but this is really a general question.

Given this table:

```
gps=# select * from sort_test;
 v1 | v2 |  data  
----+----+--------
  1 |  1 | foo 1
  2 |  2 | foo 2
  3 |  0 | foo 3
  4 |  1 | foo 4
  5 |  2 | foo 5
  6 |  0 | foo 6
  7 |  1 | foo 7
  8 |  2 | foo 8
  9 |  0 | foo 9
 10 |  1 | foo 10
(10 rows)
```

I want a combined minimum of (v2, v1), i.e. sorting v2 takes precedence over v1.  The simplest way seems to be to use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT`:

```
gps=# select v2, v1 from sort_test order by v2, v1 limit 1;
 v2 | v1 
----+----
  0 |  3
(1 row)
```

It would be nice if this would work:

```
gps=# select min(v2, v1) from sort_test ;
ERROR:  function min(numeric, numeric) does not exist
LINE 1: select min(v2, v1) from sort_test ;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The only way using `MIN` I found so far is this:

```
gps=# select v2, min(st.v1) from sort_test st where st.v2 = (select min(v2) from sort_test) group by st.v2;
 v2 | min 
----+-----
  0 |   3
(1 row)
```

Is there any other elegant way that uses standard SQL features?  (I did not want to look into [PostgreSQL Composite Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/rowtypes.html).

Comment: `least(v1, v2)`, not min().

Comment: What's wrong with order and limit? In fact it's the simplest and natural way in SQL.

Comment: least(v2, v1) does not work. I get all the rows.

Comment: @klin curiosity - I always find `LIMIT` clunky. Something including `MIN` or maybe `LEAST` for that matter would look nicer to me as it would express the intent more directly.